# How create cHash for an extbase action link

Tags: typo3, extbase

I need a link for an action, which I could send per email.

This works fine with using the viewhelper "f:link.action". Here an example:

```
<f:link.action action="changePw" id="changePw" absolute="true" arguments="{email : uSetup.uEmail, user : uSetup.uName}"></f:link.action>
```

Now I have the problem, that in the used form, the user can update his email. In this case, the link is not useful, because it includes the old email address and not the new one, which would be required!

I have looked for hours, but I could not find any useful solution.

The best would be, if could create the link in a php programm and than run a Typo3 php routine, which is creating me the required cHash value. For security resons, I would not switch off the cHash feature.
Is there a Typo3 function, which could create me the cHash value?

The other way, would be to update the viewhelper, that it is using the actual value from the email textfield. But how could I do it?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0):

A cHash is generated automatically if you generate an URL.

Data can be transfered from the client to the server in two ways: GET and POST parameters.

If you want to protect these parameters you secure them with a cHash. the hash represents a list of static parameters. These are replaced on server side overwriting any values coming from the client.

so it is clear: you can't use a value in the cHash if that value could be changed in a form. you need to exclude the emailadress from cHash for the form where the email can be changed.

---

You might define an alternative field (other name => other URL parameter) where a new email can be inserted and after the submit the email could be updated by the alternative field.

Comment: Hi Bernd, I can not exclude email, because for an email I can only use a Get parameter!

Comment: Maybe, I pointed out my problem clear enough. I want to create a link to an action via a string (by hand). First put the URL into the string. Than add action, controller and finally the parameters. This would be a complete GET, but the cHash would be missing. How can I get the cHash value for this string?

Comment: as soon, as there would be the possibility to insert (or change) any parameter in the cHash from client side the value of the cHash is obsolete.